# Ruby and Rails "Date.today" format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activesupport

In IRB, if I run following commands:

```
require 'date'
Date.today
```

I get the following output:

```
=> #<Date: 2015-09-26 ((2457292j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

But in Rails console, if I run `Date.today`, I get this:

```
=> Sat, 26 Sep 2015
```

I looked at Rails' [Date class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb) but can't find how Rails' `Date.today` displays the output differently than Ruby's output.

Can anybody tell, in Rails how `Date.today` or `Date.tomorrow` formats the date to display nicely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to your question is [`ActiveSupport`'s core extension to `Date`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb#L66-L71) class. It overrides the default implementations of `inspect` and `to_s`:

```
# Overrides the default inspect method with a human readable one, e.g., "Mon, 21 Feb 2005"
def readable_inspect
  strftime('%a, %d %b %Y')
end
alias_method :default_inspect, :inspect
alias_method :inspect, :readable_inspect
```

Command line example:

```
ruby-2.2.0 › irb
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> Date.today
=> #<Date: 2015-09-27 ((2457293j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> require 'active_support/core_ext/date'
=> true
>> Date.today
=> Sun, 27 Sep 2015
```

Answer (score 8):

Rails' [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) or [`to_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_s) methods should do what you need.

For example, using `to_s`:

```
2.2.1 :004 > Date.today.to_s(:long)
 => "September 26, 2015" 
2.2.1 :005 > Date.today.to_s(:short)
 => "26 Sep"
```

Comment: Hi Brito, my question is when I run Date.today, how rails is displaying => Sat, 26 Sep 2015?

Comment: @Lalu probably because Rails calls `to_s` somewhere when initializing Date. I'll have to research some more to confirm though.

Comment: Yes Brito, that is what I also think, but I can't figure it out. Please update your answer if you find out. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

If you run this:

```
require 'date'
p Date.today.strftime("%a, %e %b %Y")
```

You'll get this: "Sat, 26 Sep 2015"